# change color of mat-badge-content on hover

Tags: angular-material, hover

I am trying to change color of material badge on hover.
I set

```
<div matBadge="+"
     matBadgePosition="after"
     matBadgeColor="accent"
     matBadgeOverlap="false"
     matBadgeSize="large">
</div>

::ng-deep .mat-badge-content:hover {
  background-color: #98daf5;
  color: white;
}
```

But it does not change at all.

How can I change color of the badge on hover?

Answer (score 0):

When hovering div add `.mat-badge-content`.

```
::ng-deep div:hover .mat-badge-content {
    background-color: #98daf5;
    color: white;
}
```